# Use external property in annotation?

Tags: spring, properties, spring-boot

I have an annotation on class level on which it would be great if this can be externally configured

```
@QueueBinding(
value = @Queue(value = "acme", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
exchange = @Exchange(type=ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, value = "corp", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
key = "event.foo"
)
```

Is there a way to externalize the configuration and use spring configuration properties? I would like to replace:

```
exchange = @Exchange(type=ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, value = "corp", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false")
```

With a version where i can externally configure the **value = "corp"**

I tried several combinations like:

```
exchange = @Exchange(type=ExchangeTypes.TOPIC, value = "${setting.value}", durable = "true", autoDelete = "false")
```

But this does not work, any clue on how to use externalized configurable properties in a class-level annotation?

Comment: That would only work if the annotation processor would know what to do with the placeholders, i.e. resolve them else it won't work.

Comment: As an ugly hack, you might want to try get to the class before the target annotation processor does, and replace the annotation with another that has the placeholder resolved already.